# Update a property on list of object array and then retrieve the updated list

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a list of object array as shown below.I need to apply `moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");` to the all the `LastUpdate` properties and retrieve the updated new array.So how can I do that ?.I can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason a simple loop won't work?

```
for(var i = 0; i < Progress.length; i++) {
    Progress[i].LastUpdate = moment.tz(Progress[i].LastUpdate, 'America/Toronto');
}
```

**OR**

```
     Progress.forEach(function (x) {
        x.LastUpdate= moment.tz(x.LastUpdate, 'America/Toronto');
     });
```